# How to run my asp.net web application on another computer along with my SQL database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, visual-studio

Even though there are many variations of my question, none that I found address my exact issue. I have created an asp.net web application in C# using Visual Studio. I done this on my home desktop and this week I have to show my professor my application working on the lab computers at my University.

What is the best way to do this, bearing in mind I need my app along with my SQL database (that I created using Visual Studio also).

Thank you in advance for any help or advice!

Answer (score 0):

The best way you can do this is set-up your website via IIS. With this, you can host your project via LAN set-up. To know more on how you can set-up your site via IIS, you can check: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178477.aspx

If you want online, you can host it via AppHarbor which you can host your project for free, and you can now access your website via internet, not just LAN.

Comment: Does this way include my database as my app won't run without the working database? Thanks!

Comment: Yes in IIS, you call your connectionstring on your PC since you will just hosting it via IIS. If you will host it online, you will need to upload your database.